# Make PGFPlots legend look similar to ggplot2

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have attempted to make a pgfplot that resembles the R ggplot2 design to my liking (in Overleaf):

ggplot2 reference:
[image: ggplot2 reference]
pgfplots:
[image: pgfplot]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in, headsep=.2in]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{RGB}{250, 123, 72}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{RGB}{214, 156, 49}
\definecolor{mycolor3}{RGB}{8, 204, 57}
\definecolor{mycolor4}{RGB}{46, 214, 230}
\definecolor{mycolor5}{RGB}{51, 147, 242}
\definecolor{mycolor6}{RGB}{225, 89, 255}

\pgfplotstableread{
25  21293.64051 18613.91323 31873.98862 20201.15491 19397.15695 17566.30913
26  21193.76589 18779.102   32347.24257 21023.62851 19621.4149  17883.43887
27  21109.90132 19011.69904 33036.24087 21931.41012 19806.53771 18219.70238
28  20993.66263 19159.22489 33696.45995 22750.88214 20076.12341 18403.53881
29  20871.56539 19301.76474 34213.16941 23636.92229 20309.10686 18534.18704
30  20727.99842 19405.98218 34628.83502 24334.45413 20508.46222 18480.236
31  20632.70593 19379.86799 34771.7239  24644.78046 20569.51832 18269.77681
32  20391.57784 19107.72197 34407.40913 24480.75841 20360.44026 18021.424
33  20034.73211 18786.11481 33754.69647 23918.81344 19943.98187 17685.98318
34  19671.36468 18575.2717  33265.38759 23441.28649 19571.52495 17463.43294
35  19420.35433 18238.10073 32810.35748 23110.57239 19233.17729 17216.9075
36  19197.38277 18033.08128 32539.75464 22949.8436  18907.25723 17028.0751
37  18902.62025 17813.25589 32162.27682 22560.93288 18627.04636 16799.89068
38  18689.30907 17527.86456 31706.67332 22147.59074 18457.94856 16514.31736
39  18410.88568 17328.70864 31221.24106 21959.17218 18297.80812 16280.51122
40  18211.33088 17179.859   30770.09006 21721.2501  18154.49045 16069.59332
41  18049.60489 16986.18271 30394.89334 21375.15169 18039.74009 15945.06291
42  17919.92394 16818.72281 30028.821   21153.44159 17903.9438  15866.15692
43  17776.19493 16760.92756 29725.57729 20927.37372 17675.03641 15800.17216
44  17655.91259 16716.40006 29455.52041 20753.26499 17480.18092 15682.57728
45  17543.99179 16564.05025 29303.80133 20559.42415 17296.71346 15607.54292
46  17470.83466 16476.32152 29358.71218 20411.81104 17114.34791 15499.70565
47  17320.11277 16418.76061 29248.32208 20144.28955 16983.32573 15270.17002
48  17272.76569 16386.22694 29191.13262 19965.01781 16864.6065  15039.8441
49  17140.30255 16357.20591 29059.66917 19825.75376 16814.57196 14880.24215
50  17082.93859 16407.14323 29100.29263 19705.31437 16803.89693 14827.74203
51  17013.62317 16423.02115 29185.20177 19503.30397 16732.02868 14748.74879
52  16989.83495 16462.11889 29150.3172  19329.09303 16591.86217 14623.1763
53  16994.07555 16500.66319 29154.54035 19260.7424  16459.03754 14604.50123
54  17040.31075 16464.3626  29158.32971 19189.24811 16368.65627 14581.23155
55  17080.2985  16415.7017  29396.51107 19095.46389 16267.04652 14658.59687
56  17076.8083  16451.52364 29703.04056 19047.51349 16225.4109  14601.35257
57  17139.45742 16592.12643 30067.51239 18942.68029 16191.40386 14560.4474
58  17359.27533 16773.62192 30520.82731 18944.66472 16263.09511 14616.11114
59  17514.26025 17011.16507 31187.72016 18950.12439 16436.04958 14730.0064
60  17709.69661 17434.5565  32268.34655 19047.6182  16624.71993 14862.78865
61  18097.75722 18061.37934 33754.48706 19043.66181 16796.94395 15036.46858
62  18554.35542 18877.05452 35671.87692 19114.69739 17083.45214 15233.72981
63  19365.66286 19846.1889  37945.8732  19251.88477 17438.86191 15588.03269
64  20339.41677 20999.66578 40917.88995 19373.22414 17810.37896 15934.99118
65  21265.41475 22210.37698 44182.14381 19496.16401 18187.84432 16386.03249
66  22171.99723 23531.18911 47297.51313 19600.88752 18649.79001 16808.81562
67  22988.17849 24665.57209 50132.79872 19660.36805 18965.08489 17143.02989
68  23667.86293 25444.68491 52332.11714 19654.14552 19192.64358 17408.76141
69  23908.52732 25826.03935 53666.02001 19562.96897 19302.60239 17497.19815
70  23839.04737 25788.96093 54093.11853 19458.64683 19195.28616 17444.4238
71  23487.8059  25467.65044 53818.84848 19252.5878  19012.66383 17317.05386
72  22920.01983 24939.11668 52689.21716 18982.04977 18685.49727 17044.85799
73  22461.91834 24107.69071 51092.13311 18605.69131 18279.8635  16636.57166
74  21740.97223 23264.39308 49427.28927 18264.07033 17815.32757 16228.69169
75  20996.11076 22369.86675 47590.0868  17933.63046 17318.99092 15869.48757
76  20290.50409 21601.20709 45711.36338 17683.00653 16890.35422 15543.85172
77  19627.56763 20890.7266  43909.51166 17381.5503  16480.33027 15036.6032
78  19096.10708 20111.19745 42220.43835 17073.20092 16140.42198 14597.51334
79  18579.78902 19467.97066 40480.45794 16814.33762 15849.4563  14280.58056
80  18122.57505 18771.16677 39043.67637 16719.03018 15456.68891 13893.55455
81  17657.6926  18228.40047 37706.83924 16554.25524 15154.06595 13630.61519
82  17337.38927 17757.61957 36430.69671 16327.95802 14839.17743 13333.99289
83  17005.18436 17167.80534 35355.71946 16172.49445 14663.06931 13014.31531
84  16527.8045  16639.52587 34246.8 16060.2321  14489.49907 12819.66425
85  16105.13355 16176.12177 33324.05789 15955.8601  14230.74795 12605.94422
86  15626.55206 15727.5585  32408.41833 15840.04273 14049.66879 12323.54947
87  15022.68228 15444.26628 31540.36769 15658.59211 13910.22774 11960.52608
88  14303.05497 15094.33114 30848.99605 15500.90977 13733.98002 11635.01238
89  13424.80047 14833.30641 30218.76279 15358.98818 13523.54327 11395.07844
90  12455.65861 14290.99881 29767.13064 15379.26625 13272.74233 11034.42838
91  11272.94879 13633.65416 28842.49634 15223.64313 13031.80122 10792.70198
92  10080.67832 12639.505   27405.19872 14772.95084 12519.80354 10333.98721
93  8913.39769  11467.27078 25623.38575 14116.35658 11892.20537 9788.211851
94  7896.704322 10255.65711 23584.24018 13296.91946 11101.68458 9209.533856
95  7112.737628 9197.036439 21652.36099 12456.43393 10285.7227  8656.471451
96  6576.842031 8344.766491 19929.20335 11637.16883 9593.495971 8108.026085
}\mytable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=0.8\linewidth, axis x line=bottom, axis y line=left,
             grid=both, grid style={white, line width=.1pt}, major grid style={white, line width=.8pt}, 
             legend pos=outer north east, legend style={fill=gray!10, draw=none, inner sep=8pt, row sep=3pt, column sep=3pt}, 
             minor x tick num=1, minor y tick num=1, xmin = 20, xmax=100, ymin=5000, ymax=55000, 
             axis background/.style={fill=gray!10}, axis line style={draw=none}, tick style={draw=none},
             xlabel = Temperature (\si{\degreeCelsius}), ylabel = Relative Fluorescence Intensity (RFU)]
\addplot+ [color={mycolor1}, only marks, mark=*, mark options={scale=0.4}] table [x index = {0}, y index = {1}, col sep = comma] {\mytable}; 
\addplot+ [color={mycolor2}, only marks, mark=*, mark options={scale=0.4}] table [x index = {0}, y index = {2}, col sep = comma] {\mytable};
\addplot+ [color={mycolor3}, only marks, mark=*, mark options={scale=0.4}] table [x index = {0}, y index = {3}, col sep = comma] {\mytable};
\addplot+ [color={mycolor4}, only marks, mark=*, mark options={scale=0.4}] table [x index = {0}, y index = {4}, col sep = comma] {\mytable};
\addplot+ [color={mycolor5}, only marks, mark=*, mark options={scale=0.4}] table [x index = {0}, y index = {5}, col sep = comma] {\mytable};
\addplot+ [color={mycolor6}, only marks, mark=*, mark options={scale=0.4}] table [x index = {0}, y index = {6}, col sep = comma] {\mytable};
\legend{A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, I would like to also have the pgfplot legend look like the ggplot2 legend - that is,

1. have it vertically centred outside the right side of the plot,
2. give a legend title, and
3. have the dots/symbols/markers in the legend box but have the text ('A1' etc) outside to the right.

How might I do this? I am relatively new to Latex and so please excuse inefficiency in the Latex code - please give suggestions on how to improve.

Comment: Please reformate your options, they are too long. And put the data of `data1as.csv` by `inline table`

Comment: I have done some editing but I am quite new so do not know exactly what is desired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me some time to hack the output routine. There are three command related to legend:

- `\pgfplots@show@small@legendplots`: draw the legend marker on the left side.
- `\pgfplots@createlegend`: output the legend matrix
- `\pgfplots@create@axis@descriptions@`: output axis description.

`\pgfplots@create@axis@descriptions@` invokes `\pgfplots@createlegend`, and `\pgfplots@createlegend` invokes `\pgfplots@show@small@legendplots`.

Hack `\pgfplots@create@axis@descriptions@` by replacing `\pgfplots@createlegend` with

```
<some code before>
\pgfplots@createlegend
<some code after>
```

I did three main things:

1. Give a name to the legend matrix so that it can be referred later to put the legend title. This work is done by hacking `\pgfplots@createlegend`.
2. Wrap every legend image with a `local bounding box`, and then save the absolute coordinates of the `north west` anchor and `south east` anchor. This work is done by hacking `\pgfplots@show@small@legendplots`.
3. Hack `\pgfplots@create@axis@descriptions@` to draw legend title and fill the left side of legend.

### Centred outside the right side

The easiest requirement, just add the following options to `legend style`.

```
at={(axis description cs:1.1, 0.5)},
anchor=center,
```

### Legend title

Legend is actually drawn by a matrix. I patch `\pgfplots@createlegend` to give matrix a name:

```
\xpatchcmd{\pgfplots@createlegend}{%
\t@pgfplots@tokb={\matrix[/pgfplots/every axis legend]}}{
  \t@pgfplots@tokb={\matrix(legend)[/pgfplots/every axis legend]}%
}{\typeout{@@ success}}{\typeout{@@ fail}}
```

And then add the title node by patching `\pgfplots@create@axis@descriptions@`. But you also want a title alignment, so it becomes a little complex:

```
% draw code in `\pgfplots@create@axis@descriptions@'.
\ifx\pgf@legend@title\pgfutil@empty
\else
  \begingroup
  \let\pgf@legend@title@anchor\pgfutil@empty
  \afterassignment\pgf@legend@title@handle\expandlet\pgf@let@token=\pgf@legend@title@align
  \toks0=\expandafter{\pgf@legend@title@opts}
  \ifpgf@legend@title@relative@to@box
    \edef\@temp{
      \noexpand\node [inner xsep=0pt, \the\toks0, anchor=\pgf@legend@title@anchor] at (legend.\pgf@legend@anchor) {\pgf@legend@title};
    }
  \else
    \edef\@temp{
      \noexpand\node [inner xsep=0pt, yshift=4pt, \the\toks0, anchor=south west] at (lg@fill.north west) {\pgf@legend@title};
    }
  \fi
  \@temp
  \endgroup
\fi
```

and related command:

```
\def\expandlet#1{\expandafter\let\expandafter#1\expandafter}
\def\pgf@legend@title@handle{%
  \let\pgfutil@next=\pgfutil@empty%
  \ifx\pgf@let@token l%
    \let\pgfutil@next=\pgf@legend@title@left%
  \else%
    \ifx\pgf@let@token r%
      \let\pgfutil@next=\pgf@legend@title@right%
    \else%
      \ifx\pgf@let@token c%
        \let\pgfutil@next=\pgf@legend@title@center%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \pgfutil@next%
}
\def\pgf@legend@title@left eft{%
  \def\pgf@legend@title@anchor{south west}%
  \def\pgf@legend@anchor{north west}
}
\def\pgf@legend@title@right ight{%
  \def\pgf@legend@title@anchor{south east}%
  \def\pgf@legend@anchor{north east}
}
\def\pgf@legend@title@center enter{%
  \def\pgf@legend@title@anchor{south}%
  \def\pgf@legend@anchor{north}
}
```

then define styles to be used:

```
/pgfplots/.cd,
legend title/.store in=\pgf@legend@title,
legend title=\pgfutil@empty,
legend title style/.store in=\pgf@legend@title@opts,
legend title style={font=\bfseries},
legend title align/.store in=\pgf@legend@title@align,
legend title align= left,
legend title relative to box/.is if=pgf@legend@title@relative@to@box,
legend title relative to box=false,
```

then you can use `legend title=title` and `legend title style={...}` and `legend title align=<left|right|center>` to customize the title.

`legend title relative to box` is used to specify if you want the title to be aligned relative to the bouding box of legend. The default is false, which means aligning left to the half filled area.
[image]

### Partial filled

I wrap every legend image with a bounding box `lg@m`, and define a global counter to distinguish image in different rows.

```
\xpatchcmd{\pgfplots@show@small@legendplots}{%
\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/legend image code/.@cmd}\pgfeov%
}{
  \global\advance\currowNum by1
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=lg@m]
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/legend image code/.@cmd}\pgfeov%
  \end{scope}
  \coordinate (lg@m-\the\currowNum-a) at (lg@m.north west);
  \coordinate (lg@m-\the\currowNum-b) at (lg@m.south east);
  \let\oldpgf@legend@fit\pgf@legend@fit
  \xdef\pgf@legend@fit{\oldpgf@legend@fit(lg@m-\the\currowNum-a)(lg@m-\the\currowNum-b)}
%   \fi
}{}{}
```

and then fill the node that fit all saved coordinates:

```
% draw code in `\pgfplots@create@axis@descriptions@'.
\ifx\pgf@legend@fit\pgfutil@empty
\else
  \edef\@temp{
    \noexpand\node [fill=\pgf@legend@left@fill, fit=\pgf@legend@fit, inner xsep=3pt, inner ysep=4pt] {};
  }
  \begin{scope}
  \pgfplotssetlayers{back, main}
  \pgfplotsonlayer{back}
  \@temp
  \endpgfplotsonlayer
  \end{scope}
\fi
```

At last, define `left fill` style:

```
legend left fill/.store in=\pgf@legend@left@fill,
legend left fill=none,
left fill/.style={legend style={fill=none}, legend left fill=#1},
```

### Result and complete code

To show the effect of `legend title align` with `legend title relative to box`, I draw the bounding box of legend.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarelayer{back}
\pgfsetlayers{back,main}
\newif\ifpgf@legend@title@relative@to@box
% give matrix name
\xpatchcmd{\pgfplots@createlegend}{%
\t@pgfplots@tokb={\matrix[/pgfplots/every axis legend]}%
}{
  \t@pgfplots@tokb={\matrix(legend)[/pgfplots/every axis legend]}%
}{\typeout{@@ success}}{\typeout{@@ fail}}
% add counter
\xpatchcmd{\pgfplots@createlegend}{%
\let\legendplotpos=\c@pgf@countc%
}{
  \let\legendplotpos=\c@pgf@countc%
  \global\let\currowNum=\c@pgf@countd%
  \currowNum=0
}{}{}
% set partial fill coordinate
\xpatchcmd{\pgfplots@show@small@legendplots}{%
\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/legend image code/.@cmd}\pgfeov%
}{
  \global\advance\currowNum by1
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=lg@m]
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/legend image code/.@cmd}\pgfeov%
  \end{scope}
  \coordinate (lg@m-\the\currowNum-a) at (lg@m.north west);
  \coordinate (lg@m-\the\currowNum-b) at (lg@m.south east);
  \let\oldpgf@legend@fit\pgf@legend@fit
  \xdef\pgf@legend@fit{\oldpgf@legend@fit(lg@m-\the\currowNum-a)(lg@m-\the\currowNum-b)}
%   \fi
}{}{}
% add title and partial fill
\xpatchcmd{\pgfplots@create@axis@descriptions@}{\pgfplots@createlegend}{
  \let\pgf@legend@fit\pgfutil@empty
  \pgfplots@createlegend
  % partial fill
  \ifx\pgf@legend@fit\pgfutil@empty
  \else
    \edef\@temp{
      \noexpand\node [fill=\pgf@legend@left@fill, fit=\pgf@legend@fit, inner xsep=3pt, inner ysep=4pt] (lg@fill) {};
    }
    \begin{scope}
    \pgfplotssetlayers{back, main}
    \pgfplotsonlayer{back}
    \@temp
    \endpgfplotsonlayer
    \end{scope}
  \fi
  % add title
  \ifx\pgf@legend@title\pgfutil@empty
  \else
    \begingroup
    \let\pgf@legend@title@anchor\pgfutil@empty
    \afterassignment\pgf@legend@title@handle\expandlet\pgf@let@token=\pgf@legend@title@align
    \toks0=\expandafter{\pgf@legend@title@opts}
    \ifpgf@legend@title@relative@to@box
      \edef\@temp{
        \noexpand\node [inner xsep=0pt, \the\toks0, anchor=\pgf@legend@title@anchor] at (legend.\pgf@legend@anchor) {\pgf@legend@title};
      }
    \else
      \edef\@temp{
        \noexpand\node [inner xsep=0pt, yshift=4pt, \the\toks0, anchor=south west] at (lg@fill.north west) {\pgf@legend@title};
      }
    \fi
    \@temp
    \endgroup
  \fi
}{\typeout{yy succ}}{}
\def\expandlet#1{\expandafter\let\expandafter#1\expandafter}
\def\pgf@legend@title@handle{%
  \let\pgfutil@next=\pgfutil@empty%
  \ifx\pgf@let@token l%
    \let\pgfutil@next=\pgf@legend@title@left%
  \else%
    \ifx\pgf@let@token r%
      \let\pgfutil@next=\pgf@legend@title@right%
    \else%
      \ifx\pgf@let@token c%
        \let\pgfutil@next=\pgf@legend@title@center%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \pgfutil@next%
}
\def\pgf@legend@title@left eft{%
  \def\pgf@legend@title@anchor{south west}%
  \def\pgf@legend@anchor{north west}
}
\def\pgf@legend@title@right ight{%
  \def\pgf@legend@title@anchor{south east}%
  \def\pgf@legend@anchor{north east}
}
\def\pgf@legend@title@center enter{%
  \def\pgf@legend@title@anchor{south}%
  \def\pgf@legend@anchor{north}
}

\tikzset{
  /pgfplots/.cd,
  legend title/.store in=\pgf@legend@title,
  legend title=\pgfutil@empty,
  legend title style/.store in=\pgf@legend@title@opts,
  legend title style={font=\bfseries},
  legend title align/.store in=\pgf@legend@title@align,
  legend title align=left,
  legend title relative to box/.is if=pgf@legend@title@relative@to@box,
  legend title relative to box=false,
  legend left fill/.store in=\pgf@legend@left@fill,
  legend left fill=none,
  left fill/.style={legend style={fill=none}, legend left fill=#1},
}
\makeatother
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}


\pgfplotstableread{
25  21293.64051 18613.91323 31873.98862 20201.15491 19397.15695 17566.30913
26  21193.76589 18779.102   32347.24257 21023.62851 19621.4149  17883.43887
27  21109.90132 19011.69904 33036.24087 21931.41012 19806.53771 18219.70238
28  20993.66263 19159.22489 33696.45995 22750.88214 20076.12341 18403.53881
29  20871.56539 19301.76474 34213.16941 23636.92229 20309.10686 18534.18704
30  20727.99842 19405.98218 34628.83502 24334.45413 20508.46222 18480.236
31  20632.70593 19379.86799 34771.7239  24644.78046 20569.51832 18269.77681
32  20391.57784 19107.72197 34407.40913 24480.75841 20360.44026 18021.424
33  20034.73211 18786.11481 33754.69647 23918.81344 19943.98187 17685.98318
34  19671.36468 18575.2717  33265.38759 23441.28649 19571.52495 17463.43294
35  19420.35433 18238.10073 32810.35748 23110.57239 19233.17729 17216.9075
36  19197.38277 18033.08128 32539.75464 22949.8436  18907.25723 17028.0751
37  18902.62025 17813.25589 32162.27682 22560.93288 18627.04636 16799.89068
38  18689.30907 17527.86456 31706.67332 22147.59074 18457.94856 16514.31736
39  18410.88568 17328.70864 31221.24106 21959.17218 18297.80812 16280.51122
40  18211.33088 17179.859   30770.09006 21721.2501  18154.49045 16069.59332
41  18049.60489 16986.18271 30394.89334 21375.15169 18039.74009 15945.06291
42  17919.92394 16818.72281 30028.821   21153.44159 17903.9438  15866.15692
43  17776.19493 16760.92756 29725.57729 20927.37372 17675.03641 15800.17216
44  17655.91259 16716.40006 29455.52041 20753.26499 17480.18092 15682.57728
45  17543.99179 16564.05025 29303.80133 20559.42415 17296.71346 15607.54292
46  17470.83466 16476.32152 29358.71218 20411.81104 17114.34791 15499.70565
47  17320.11277 16418.76061 29248.32208 20144.28955 16983.32573 15270.17002
48  17272.76569 16386.22694 29191.13262 19965.01781 16864.6065  15039.8441
49  17140.30255 16357.20591 29059.66917 19825.75376 16814.57196 14880.24215
50  17082.93859 16407.14323 29100.29263 19705.31437 16803.89693 14827.74203
51  17013.62317 16423.02115 29185.20177 19503.30397 16732.02868 14748.74879
52  16989.83495 16462.11889 29150.3172  19329.09303 16591.86217 14623.1763
53  16994.07555 16500.66319 29154.54035 19260.7424  16459.03754 14604.50123
54  17040.31075 16464.3626  29158.32971 19189.24811 16368.65627 14581.23155
55  17080.2985  16415.7017  29396.51107 19095.46389 16267.04652 14658.59687
56  17076.8083  16451.52364 29703.04056 19047.51349 16225.4109  14601.35257
57  17139.45742 16592.12643 30067.51239 18942.68029 16191.40386 14560.4474
58  17359.27533 16773.62192 30520.82731 18944.66472 16263.09511 14616.11114
59  17514.26025 17011.16507 31187.72016 18950.12439 16436.04958 14730.0064
60  17709.69661 17434.5565  32268.34655 19047.6182  16624.71993 14862.78865
61  18097.75722 18061.37934 33754.48706 19043.66181 16796.94395 15036.46858
62  18554.35542 18877.05452 35671.87692 19114.69739 17083.45214 15233.72981
63  19365.66286 19846.1889  37945.8732  19251.88477 17438.86191 15588.03269
64  20339.41677 20999.66578 40917.88995 19373.22414 17810.37896 15934.99118
65  21265.41475 22210.37698 44182.14381 19496.16401 18187.84432 16386.03249
66  22171.99723 23531.18911 47297.51313 19600.88752 18649.79001 16808.81562
67  22988.17849 24665.57209 50132.79872 19660.36805 18965.08489 17143.02989
68  23667.86293 25444.68491 52332.11714 19654.14552 19192.64358 17408.76141
69  23908.52732 25826.03935 53666.02001 19562.96897 19302.60239 17497.19815
70  23839.04737 25788.96093 54093.11853 19458.64683 19195.28616 17444.4238
71  23487.8059  25467.65044 53818.84848 19252.5878  19012.66383 17317.05386
72  22920.01983 24939.11668 52689.21716 18982.04977 18685.49727 17044.85799
73  22461.91834 24107.69071 51092.13311 18605.69131 18279.8635  16636.57166
74  21740.97223 23264.39308 49427.28927 18264.07033 17815.32757 16228.69169
75  20996.11076 22369.86675 47590.0868  17933.63046 17318.99092 15869.48757
76  20290.50409 21601.20709 45711.36338 17683.00653 16890.35422 15543.85172
77  19627.56763 20890.7266  43909.51166 17381.5503  16480.33027 15036.6032
78  19096.10708 20111.19745 42220.43835 17073.20092 16140.42198 14597.51334
79  18579.78902 19467.97066 40480.45794 16814.33762 15849.4563  14280.58056
80  18122.57505 18771.16677 39043.67637 16719.03018 15456.68891 13893.55455
81  17657.6926  18228.40047 37706.83924 16554.25524 15154.06595 13630.61519
82  17337.38927 17757.61957 36430.69671 16327.95802 14839.17743 13333.99289
83  17005.18436 17167.80534 35355.71946 16172.49445 14663.06931 13014.31531
84  16527.8045  16639.52587 34246.8 16060.2321  14489.49907 12819.66425
85  16105.13355 16176.12177 33324.05789 15955.8601  14230.74795 12605.94422
86  15626.55206 15727.5585  32408.41833 15840.04273 14049.66879 12323.54947
87  15022.68228 15444.26628 31540.36769 15658.59211 13910.22774 11960.52608
88  14303.05497 15094.33114 30848.99605 15500.90977 13733.98002 11635.01238
89  13424.80047 14833.30641 30218.76279 15358.98818 13523.54327 11395.07844
90  12455.65861 14290.99881 29767.13064 15379.26625 13272.74233 11034.42838
91  11272.94879 13633.65416 28842.49634 15223.64313 13031.80122 10792.70198
92  10080.67832 12639.505   27405.19872 14772.95084 12519.80354 10333.98721
93  8913.39769  11467.27078 25623.38575 14116.35658 11892.20537 9788.211851
94  7896.704322 10255.65711 23584.24018 13296.91946 11101.68458 9209.533856
95  7112.737628 9197.036439 21652.36099 12456.43393 10285.7227  8656.471451
96  6576.842031 8344.766491 19929.20335 11637.16883 9593.495971 8108.026085
}\mytable
\begin{document}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{RGB}{250, 123, 72}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{RGB}{214, 156, 49}
\definecolor{mycolor3}{RGB}{8, 204, 57}
\definecolor{mycolor4}{RGB}{46, 214, 230}
\definecolor{mycolor5}{RGB}{51, 147, 242}
\definecolor{mycolor6}{RGB}{225, 89, 255}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=bottom,
  grid style={white, line width=.1pt},
  major grid style={white, line width=.8pt},
  legend title relative to box,
  legend style={
    at={(axis description cs:1.1, 0.5)},
    anchor=center,
    left fill=gray!20,
    draw,
    inner sep=8pt,
    row sep=3pt,
    column sep=3pt
  },
  legend title=title,
  axis y line=left,
  xlabel = Temperature (\si{\degreeCelsius}),
  ylabel = Relative Fluorescence Intensity (RFU),
  scale only axis,
  grid=both,
  minor x tick num=1,
  width=0.8\linewidth,
  minor y tick num=1,
  xmin = 20,xmax=100,
  ymin=5000, ymax=55000,
  axis background/.style={fill=gray!10},
  axis line style={draw=none},
  tick style={draw=none}
]
\addplot+ [color={mycolor1}, only marks, mark=*, mark options={scale=0.4}] table [x index = {0}, y index = {1}, col sep = comma] {\mytable};
\addplot+ [color={mycolor2}, only marks, mark=*, mark options={scale=0.4}] table [x index = {0}, y index = {2}, col sep = comma] {\mytable};
\addplot+ [color={mycolor3}, only marks, mark=*, mark options={scale=0.4}] table [x index = {0}, y index = {3}, col sep = comma] {\mytable};
\addplot+ [color={mycolor4}, only marks, mark=*, mark options={scale=0.4}] table [x index = {0}, y index = {4}, col sep = comma] {\mytable};
\addplot+ [color={mycolor5}, only marks, mark=*, mark options={scale=0.4}] table [x index = {0}, y index = {5}, col sep = comma] {\mytable};
\addplot+ [color={mycolor6}, only marks, mark=*, mark options={scale=0.4}] table [x index = {0}, y index = {6}, col sep = comma] {\mytable};
\legend{A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for all this, especially for the legend title. I have a follow-up question: how would one edit the code to make the legend title left-aligned with the legend box? And for the 'partial filled' legend box, would it be possible to achieve this manually using nodes and not legends?

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: +1(00): Very professional answer!